# Accessing the database API directly with client-side JS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, database-connection, influxdb

I need to build a simple web front-end which will be mostly used to plot some data fetched from a database. The database (namely, InfluxDB) exposes a HTML API which I could just conveniently call directly from my Javascript front-end. I'm putting login service in front of it (AWS Cognito).

However,  once a user logs in, they can easily discover my API endpoints in the client-side code, and therefore make arbitrary queries and possibly abuse it or just steal all my data. How can I avoid it? Is it possible to somehow make the API accessible only to the app's front-end? If not, what is the best practice I should follow here?

Comment: is the influxdb also running on AWS?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge Yes, on an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest maybe creating a Node.js based webservice that would wrap your REST API. Using the Express module it's only a few lines to put together a simple REST service and call out to other APIs.

```
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get("/test", function(req, res, next){
    res.status(200).send('Hello World');
});

app.get("/testapi", function(req, res, next){

    // Read from another API and return result...
    var options = {
        url: "https://httpbin.org/ip",
        method: "get"
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('error:', error);
            res.status(500).send(error.message);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(body);
        }
    });

});

let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Express listening on ${port}..`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your InfluxDB is also running on EC2, the fastest and safest approach would be to only allow your web application access to the influxdb instance by limiting it in the [security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#vpc-security-groups).

Image that your webapp is running on the default VPC with CIDR 172.31.0.0/16 and that influxdb is running on port 8086. Then simply create a security group with an INBOUND rule that port 8086 can only be reached from inside your AWS account (So IP 172.31.0.0/16) and attach it to your Influx EC2 instance. make sure other inbound rules allowing access to 0.0.0.0/0 are removed.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but if it's the client-side code that's querying the database, then it's not executed from inside the VPC, but from a user machine, is that correct? Then doesn't your solution make it impossible to call the API from client-side?